# Compute $\sum_{i=0}^{100}\lfloor i^{3/2}\rfloor+\sum_{j=0}^{1000}\lfloor i^{2/3}\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm trying to find the value of $\sum_{i=0}^{100}\lfloor i^{3/2}\rfloor+\sum_{j=0}^{1000}\lfloor i^{2/3}\rfloor$.

The second sum is obvious, since it's over $j$ instead of $i$. I thought there would be cancellation in the first sum. But it really confuses me how to deal with the square roots inside the floor function.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: In $\sum_{i=0}^{100}[i^{3/2}]+\sum_{j=0}^{1000}[i^{2/3}]$, should the second summation not be $\sum_{j=0}^{1000}[j^{2/3}]$ instead since i has no meaning there? Also, since you indicate the square brackets signify the floor function, note the generally more common, and I believe more proper, symbols for this are the $\lfloor$ and $\rfloor$ ones, with \lfloor and \rfloor being the MathJax statements to use.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thank you for comment. Yes the square brackets denote the integer part of the number inside. And for the 2nd sum, the question I got is printed like that. I am not sure if it's a misprint for it. It still makes sense though because it's gonna be like counting 1000 times.

Comment: You're welcome for the comment. I don't understand how "It still makes sense though because it's gonna be like counting 1000 times" because it's not clear to me *what* you are counting $1000$ times. Instead, I suspect it's more likely a misprint.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I'm counting $\lfloor i^{2/3}\rfloor$ 1001 times actually. Each time the counting variable $j$ increases by 1, we just get another $\lfloor i^{2/3}\rfloor$ added to the sum.

Comment: Unless by $i$ you mean something like $\sqrt{-1}$, which doesn't make sense in this context, what is the value of $i$ in $\lfloor i^{2/3}\rfloor$ that you're counting $1001$ times?

Comment: @JohnOmielan the value of $i$ is out of my reach for now. And it doesn't matter actually. We just leave it there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109323/discussion-between-botrance-and-john-omielan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of functions inverse to each other (I mean, $x\mapsto x^{3/2}$ and $x\mapsto x^{2/3}$; look also at the limits) indicates that the "$i$" in the second sum is almost certainly a typo, making one compute the first sum mechanically. With "$j$" in place, it has a somewhat "nice" solution at least. Namely, to compute $$A_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n^2}\lfloor i^{3/2}\rfloor+\sum_{j=0}^{n^3}\lfloor j^{2/3}\rfloor,$$ denote $S_n=\{(i,j) : 1\leqslant i\leqslant n^2,1\leqslant j\leqslant n^3\}$ and observe that the 1st (resp. 2nd) sum is equal to the number of pairs $(i,j)\in S_n$ such that $i^3\geqslant j^2$ (resp. $i^3\leqslant j^2$). Thus, $A_n$ counts each element $(i,j)\in S_n$ once if $i^3\neq j^2$ and twice if $i^3=j^2$; the latter happens if and only if $i=k^2$ and $j=k^3$ for some $k$, $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$. Hence, $$A_n=n^5+n.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I have only one question. Shouldn't the range for $i$ or $j$ start with $0$?

Comment: @Botrance: No. Otherwise the "... is equal to the number of pairs..." ceases to hold (consider $n=1$, or even $n=0$, and see what happens). Anyway, the terms with $i=0$ or $j=0$ are zero and can be thrown away.

Comment: You're right. I was being stupid. Thanks a lot!